# Как импортировать значения API в PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-spreadsheet

Вытащил данные из Google Sheets API
Парсинг прошел успешно, прилагаю скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу вытащить данные в PostgreSQL

*выбрал самый простой способ с помощью команд sql*

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host=host,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database=db_name
)
connection.autocommit = True

# for row in rows:
#     st1 = row[0], st2 = row[1], st3 = row[2], st4 = row[3]

# with connection.cursor() as cursor:
#     cursor.execute(
#         """CREATE TABLE test_c (
#         №   integer,
#         заказ_№ integer,
#         стоимость_$ integer,
#         стоимость_РУБ integer,
#         срок_поставки   date);"""
#     )

col1 = [row[0] for row in rows]
col2 = [row[1] for row in rows]
col3 = [row[2] for row in rows]
col4 = [row[2]*67 for row in rows] #курс $ через API вытащю, но пока так
col5 = [row[3] for row in rows]
print(col1)

"""INSERT data into a table"""
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(
        """INSERT INTO test_c
        (№, заказ_№, стоимость_$, стоимость_РУБ, срок_поставки)
        VALUES (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);"""
    )

"""UPDATE data into a table"""
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(
        """UPDATE test_c 
        SET № = [i for i in col1];"""
    )
```

Но что-то явно делаю не так.

Хелпаните, плиз!

Comment: У меня к Вам только один вопрос. Вы где прочитали, что можно вот так как вы сделали? Хотя можете не отвечать, я и так знаю. Вы нигде не читали. Вам просто лень было. Как было лень прочитать правила данного ресурса.

Comment: Я читал статьи и смотрел видео те что мне было понятны. Из документации Postres вытаскивал команды. 
И Дело совсем не в лени:) Знать бы где и что искать...
Сам придумал почему бы не использовать List comprehension. Хотя видел что терминал показывает якобы нет такой колонки. 
Понимал что шляпу* написал, но методом проб и ошибок - ковыряюсь и постигаю Джангу, Питон, Реляционные СУБД.

И Спасибо за ответ! 
Очень помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from psycopg2 import connect
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

data = [['38', '1287751', '1891', '17.05.2022'],
        ['39', '1498932', '1162', '21.05.2022'],
        ['40', '1897398', '414', '01.06.2022'],
        ['41', '1810448', '1668', '11.05.2022'],
        ['42', '1168728', '658', '03.05.2022'],
        ['43', '1560222', '1587', '11.05.2022'],
        ['44', '1592686', '514', '23.05.2022'],
        ['45', '1786437', '618', '28.05.2022'],
        ['46', '1485012', '1124', '09.05.2022'],
        ['47', '1741017', '514', '16.05.2022'],
        ['48', '1497493', '1198', '30.05.2022'],
        ['49', '1877503', '1204', '29.05.2022'],
        ['50', '1426726', '1997', '20.05.2022']]

c = connect(
        # your connection params
)
cr = c.cursor()
cr.execute(
        """
        create table if not exists rate(
                transaction_id int primary key ,
                order_id int,
                amount_usd numeric,

                -- Сделано для примера,
                -- при наличии курса заменить
                amount_rub numeric generated always as ( amount_usd * 60 ) stored ,
                term date
        );
        """
)

execute_values(
        cr,
        """
        insert into rate (transaction_id, order_id, amount_usd, term) 
           VALUES %s
                on conflict (transaction_id) do update 
                        set order_id = excluded.order_id, 
                        amount_usd = excluded.amount_usd, 
                        term = excluded.term;
        """,
        data,
        template="(%s, %s, %s, to_date(%s::text, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))",
        page_size=100
)
c.commit()
cr.close()
c.close()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]